# Error (-10005, 'IPC timeout') metatrader5 when initializing with Python

Tags: python, timeout, metatrader5

I've already connected to the mt5 terminal and server and gathered the data I wanted, but sometimes, almost randomly, the mt5.initialize returns the **Error (-10005, 'IPC timeout')**
That's how I initialize it.

```py
import MetaTrader5 as mt5
 
# establish connection to the MetaTrader 5 terminal
if not mt5.initialize(login=self.login, server=self.server,password=self.password):
    print("Error code:", mt5.last_error()))
    mt5.shutdown()
```

**I've already tried some solutions that can be found** here in StackOverflow or some other communities, but none of them work consistenly, here are some of those:

```py
if not mt5.initialize(path=self.path, login=self.login, server=self.server, password=self.password):
    print("Error code:", mt5.last_error())
    mt5.shutdown()
```

or

```py
if not mt5.initialize():
    print("Error code:", mt5.last_error())
    mt5.shutdown()
```

or even

```py
 if not mt5.initialize(path=self.path):
    print("Error code:", mt5.last_error())
else:
    if mt5.login(login=self.login, server=self.server, password=self.password):
        print("logged in succesffully")
    else: 
        print("Error code:", mt5.last_error())
```

And none of them corrects the possibility of getting the **Error -10005** now and then. The MetaTrader5 documentation says it's a **internal timeout**, but how to solve it so my program become more stable?